# How does Vim declare the filetype for Js or other types

Tags: vim, neovim

For making my own snippet for `js`, Vim can't use `js` as a type to create my snippet.

```
autocmd FileType js :call Foo()
```

How do I choose the correct Vim FileType?

Comment: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html#filetype-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the article linked in the comments, you can do this using an autocmd in your vimrc. However, I find it can be cleaner to instead leverage vim's runtime path structure to set filetype-specific settings.

#### TL;DR

Put your filetype specific commands such as `inoremap ,f ()...` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`. If any of these directories don't exist, create them. You can do similar things for other languages (e.g. put html bindings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`, etc).

#### Explanation

The vim runtime path is just where vim looks for configuration files and related things when it starts up (just like how it reads `~/.vimrc`). First it will read some system-wide things from `/etc`, and then it will read the contents of `~/.vim`. The `after` directory, as the name suggests, will be read after other settings, and though it is probably not necessary to put this type of thing in `after`, it won't hurt (it makes sure it won't get overwritten by system-wide configuration). Within `after` is the `ftplugin` directory, which is where filetype-specific config will go. You could also put an `ftplugin` directory directly in `~/.vim`, and it would do the same thing (except it would get read earlier. The files you put in this directory will work similar to how the autocmd would work. I just prefer to do things this way, because I find it neater than having a bunch of autocmds in my vimrc. For more detailed info about the vim runtime path and how you can use it, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gs1VDYnS-Ac). The whole thing isn't about the runtime path, but it does have a very good explanation in there.

Of course, you can still use autocmds if you would like to (and I think your only problem there is that your autocmd must say `Filetype javascript` instead of `Filetype js`).

Comment: BTW, the mapping should be buffer local.